# A group-like structure with multiplicative zero instead of the identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My question is whether the structure in the title is known and has a name.

For clarity: the structure is a finite group like structure $G$ but instead of the identity we have a zero element $0\in G$ such that $0 g=0$ for all $g\in G$.

The prototypical example of this structure is the *subset* of $n\times n$ matrices denoted with  $M_{ij}$  for $i,j=1,...,n$  (with matrix multiplication as the group product) and  defined by having $1$ in the $i,j$ position and $0$ everywhere else, and one additional matrix $M_0$ that is the all zeros matrix.

Answer (score 9):

A set with a binary associative operation is a **semigroup.**

A semigroup that has a two-sided identity element is a **monoid.**

A monoid in which every element has a two-sided inverse is a **group.**

Given a semigroup $S$, an element $0\in S$ such that $0g=g0=0$ for all $g\in S$ is called a **zero element.**

You have "semigroups with zero" and "monoids with zero." Note that a zero element, if it exists, must be unique.

The set of $n \times n$ matrices with matrix multiplication are a (non-commutative) monoid with zero. Note that it does not, as you write, "have a zero *instead* of an identity." Rather, it has a zero **in addition** to having an identity (which is not a problem, since $0e = 0$).

If your object has a zero but no identity, then it is a semigroup with a zero. An example of a semigroup with zero that is not a monoid could be the even integers under multiplication.

The set of $n \times n$ matrices with a single $1$ and zeros elsewhere, plus the zero matrix, would be a semigroup with zero.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, "semigroups with zero" sounds like a good name for it. I did not mean all $n \times n$ matrices. I edited the post to clarify that better.

Comment: @oleg: I've edited the post and deleted the other comment.

Comment: +1 Another common phrase for "zero element" is [absorbing element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_element)

Comment: Shouldn't the definition be $0g = g0 = 0$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Well, in each commutative ring $R$ (such as the ring of integers or the ring of square matrices), the zero element $0$ is absorbing, i.e., $r0 = 0 = 0r$.

Indeed, $0 = 0 + 0$ and so $r0 = r(0+0) = r0 + r0$. By adding the additive inverse $-r0$ to both sides (i.e., $r0 + (-r0) = 0$), $0 = r0$.